# Background-color overlapping border-radius

Tags: html, css

I am making this page where I wanted a rounded box in the middle.
My issue is (as seen in the picture) that I have a div with background-color that is overlapping the div behind with the border-radius.

[Her is the image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzie.png)

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code

Comment: Have you tried overflow: hidden?

Comment: Also, note that if you use < table >, you'll have problems with border radius.

Comment: I added the overflow: hidden - to the div and it worked!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the outer div(the one with the border radius) add overflow:hidden.  If for whatever reason you want to avoid that, you can also add an additional border radius to the child element.